# Prevent LVM from activating all LVs upon connecting SAN storage?

Tags: linux, lvm, iscsi

We have a cluster of Proxmox VE servers with shared SAN storage. The storage server provides a big LUN through iSCSI. We use `iscsiadm` on the PVE hosts to load the storage. Per our workload, we setup one VG backed by one PV on the SAN. For some reasons the iSCSI disk doesn't load properly on startup (`/dev/sdb` not showing up), and we had to `iscsiadm --login` manually. The problem is, all LVs on the VG on that disk load as "active", with `lvs` showing `-wi-a-----` as flags. This is undesirable for a cluster setup, as Proxmox expect volumes associated with powered-off VMs and CTs be "freed" (i.e. `lvchange -an`). I have to manually run `vgchange -an` every time the iSCSI drive is mounted.

Is there a way to stop LVM from activating all logical volumes upon attachment of a new VG (or this particular VG, or the iSCSI disk)? I need the solution on Debian.

Comment: I suggest you try [this](https://serverfault.com/a/678654/126632).